# pageinit does not fire in jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-init

Can anyone help with this?

The pageinit does not fire!

JS

```
$(document).off("pageinit pageshow", "#fachub").on("pageinit", "#fachub", function() {

    alert("Hello");

});
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="../js/script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos jqm-home jqm-cori carehub" data-theme="c" id="fachub">
            <h3 id="appendtoh3">Facilities Hub</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

When i load the page on the browser i do not get any alerts at all,
it is just the blank page.

Comment: Does script.js include jquery and jquery mobile? Where is the jQM css link?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pagecreate` instead of `pageinit`. The [documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) says that pageinit was deprecated in jQM 1.4.0.

```
$(document).off("pagecreate pageshow", "#fachub").on("pagecreate", "#fachub", function() {

    alert("Hello");

});
```